# how to run export command from Scala code to add new environment variable on Linux?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using play framework for a simple web project and I want to set configuration in the application.conf file from a web interface, for instance, I want to update the application secret in application.conf from a web interface, I know that is impossible to modify from the controller the application.conf file, so I'm trying to create a new environment variable from the controller and calling it in the application.conf file, the problem is I could not use the export command in Scala code to create the new environment variable, I tried these ones but no good result:

First one:

`val test = "export MYVAR = test"
  val ex = test.!!`

Second one:

`val pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh","-c","export VAR=" + "PATH-TO-ADD" + " && exec").start()`

Third one:

`Process("export", Seq("MY_VAR=ttt")).!!`

Comment: This can't work. To change the secret you will need change it wherever it is read form (probably application.conf) and restart the play app.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible because of the way environment variables work.

Environment variables belong to a specific process and only code running in that process can change the environment. Sub-processes will be initialised with any exported variables in the parent process, but a sub-process can't change the environment variables of its parent process.

Your Scala program is running in a sub-process so it can only affect the environment for itself and any child processes. It cannot change the environment of the shell from which it was spawned.

If you give some details of why you want to do this it might be possible to solve that problem another way.

Comment: thanks. In my case I want to set a new environment variable by a function and this variable will be read by play framework configuration file.